EF Core finding attribute via convention that I don't want it to
I have a class library representing my EF Core 9 database. That library includes a NuGet package of attributes that are set on the model. It's used to configure the generation of PUML files at deployment via GitHub actions.
However, I don't want consumers of the database project to have to include those attributes in their projects. I can set the attribute package to PrivateAssets="all" but when OnModelCreating runs it throws an exception as the conventions (?) are scanning all the attributes.
How can I tell EF Core to ignore those specific attributes? I tried registering a convention via the following, but that runs after the normal ones and never gets hit.
internal class IgnorePumlGeneratorAttributesConvention : IEntityTypeAddedConvention
{
    public void ProcessEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, IConventionContext<IConventionEntityTypeBuilder> context) {
        foreach (var annotation in entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.GetAnnotations())
            if (annotation.Name.StartsWith("PumlGenerator"))
                entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.RemoveAnnotation(annotation.Name);
    }
}

It's a long exception chain but here's the top part:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PumlGenerator.Attributes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'PumlGenerator.Attributes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(QCallModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctorWithParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.TypeAttributeConventionBase`1.ProcessEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)


Don't think that EF Core annotations are related to attributes. Which exception is thrown by EF Core?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I added the exception to the question description.

I have no perfect solution, maybe just include source files of these attributes into your library. I hope generator just expects name, namespace and attribute parameters to match.
